# solutions of polynomial with coefficients from Ring R

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $R$ be a ring and $p$ be a polynomial of degree $n$ with coefficients from $R$. Then is it true that $p$ can have at most $n$ roots in $R$?

Comment: Another quick counter-example is the Quaternions, where $x^2 + 1 = 0$ has a continuum of roots.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not true. If $R=\Bbb Z_8$ the equation $X^2=1$ has four solutions.

Answer (score 3):

If $R$ is an integral domain, then yes.

Otherwise (assuming this is a commutative, uital ring), if you take $a, b\in R\setminus \{0\}$ such that $a\neq b$ and $ab = 0$, then the polynomial
$$
p = (x-a)(x-b)
$$
has at least three roots $x = 0, x = a, x = b$.